# How to wait until the file is closed

Tags: linux

I have an external process that start a write to a file. 
 How do I write script that waits until the file is closed (when the other process done with the writing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this:

- If you can, start the process from your script. The script will continue when the process terminates and that means it can't write any more data to the file.
- If you can't control the process but you know that the process terminates after writing the file, you can find out the process ID and then check if the process is still running with `kill -0 $PID`. If `$?` is `0` afterwards, the process is still alive.
- If that's not possible, then you can use `lsof -np $PID` to get a list of all open files for this process and check if your file is in the list. This is somewhat slow, though.

**[EDIT]** Note that all these approaches are somewhat brittle. The correct solution is to have the external process write the file using a temporary name and then rename it as soon as it's done.

The rename makes sure that everyone else either sees the whole file with all the data or nothing.

Comment: how about `! lsof -- /path/to/file`?

Comment: @RubyTuesdayDONO: What about it?

Comment: i was suggesting it as a more direct way to query whether any process has that specific file open (versus `grep`'ing through a list of all files open by the most likely process). your secondary recommendation around renaming temp files into place once finished seems like a superior option — i just want to highlight that `lsof` is a sophisticated command with multiple vectors for homing in on exactly the desired information.

Comment: @RubyTuesdayDONO: Ah. I suggest to always specify the option `-n` for use cases like this so `lsof` doesn't spend a lot of time doing DNS lookups.

Comment: i didn't observe any DNS lookups on my Fedora (OpenVZ) VPS when using `strace` with a filename argument (e.g., `cat >>file & strace -f -e trace=network lsof -- file`) — although i'd agree it's a good habit to be explicit where possible since implementations can vary wildly :]

Comment: The behavior doesn't depend on `lsof` but on the process which `lsof` analyzes. Run it on a busy web server and it might take half an hour to resolve all the client addresses.

Comment: ah, right … especially since other processes (besides one that we're expecting) could have the target file open.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way: let the script execute the program and wait until it's finished.

Answer (score 2):

Loop until file is stable approach, this should work if you are waiting for experiment results  (so you don't need real-time event handling):

```
EXPECTED_WRITE_INTERVAL_SECONDS=1
FILE="file.txt"
while : ; do
        omod=$(stat -c %Y $FILE)
        #  echo "OLD: $omod"
        sleep $EXPECTED_WRITE_INTERVAL_SECONDS
        nmod=$(stat -c %Y $FILE)
        #  echo "NEW: $nmod"
        if [ $omod == $nmod ] ; then
                break
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a small C program using [`inotify`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify). The program should:

1. Create an `inotify` instance.
2. Add a watch to the instance for the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event for the file path of interest.
3. Wait for the event.
4. Exit with an appropriate code.

Then in your script, invoke the program with the file path as an argument.

You could extend this by adding a timeout argument, and allowing different events to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't nice, and it makes me feel dirty writing it... /tmp/foo.txt is the file being tested...

```
#!/bin/bash

until [ "$( find /proc/*/fd 2> /dev/null | 
   xargs -i{} readlink {} |
   grep -c '^/tmp/foo.txt$' )" == "0" ]; do

   sleep 1;
done;
```